# How to set a different label for tabular input - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have followed this guide http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html to build a tabular input. But in my case, I want to add a different label for each input. How can I do that?

Update action:

```
public function actionUpdate()
{
    $emailModel = EMAIL::find()->indexBy('ID')->all();

    if (Model::loadMultiple($emailModel, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($emailModel)) {
        foreach ($emailModel as $email) {
            $email->save(false);
        }
        return $this->redirect('update');
    }

    return $this->render('update', ['emailModel' => $emailModel]);
}
```

Update View

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
        <?php foreach ($emailModel as $index => $email) { ?>
            <?= $form->field($email, "[$index]CONTENT")->textArea(['maxlength' => true])->label(false) ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>
 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I'm on learning Yii2. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the label for multiple models is the same as for one model.

**1)** To retrieve it from `attributeLabels()` or generate automatically based on according database column name (in case it's `ActiveRecord` and there is no according entry in `attributeLabels()`) just omit `->label(false)` call:

```
<?= $form->field($email, "[$index]CONTENT")->textArea(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

**2)** To apply custom label just for this form:

```
<?= $form->field($email, "[$index]CONTENT")->textArea(['maxlength' => true])->label('Your custom label') ?>
```

**3)** To have different label for each `$model` in a set just create helper function and call it in the loop:

```
function getCustomLabel($model, $index) 
{
    $number = $index + 1;
    return "Content for model number $number";
}

<?= $form->field($email, "[$index]CONTENT")->textArea(['maxlength' => true])->label(getCustomLabel($model, $index)) ?>
```

Check the official docs:

- [yii\widgets\ActiveField label()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#label()-detail)
- [Creating forms (ActiveField)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html#activefield)

Comment: I have customize your answer and it's working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add `label(label name)` used as per [Tabular Input](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html)

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?php foreach ($emailModel as $index => $email) { ?>
        <?= $form->field($email, "[$index]CONTENT")->textArea(['maxlength' => true])->label('Email '.$index+1) ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Refer the Docs
[Yii2 Active Field](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html#activefield)